# Why is nfs server not seeing resized filesystem size?

Tags: nfs, lvm, ext4, ext3, nfs4

On the NFS server, when I extend the the logical volume (using lvm2) and subsequently the ext4 fs on top of it (using resize2fs), I'm able to see the new size locally with df. But the NFS clients which mount this partition through NFS still see the old size. Rebooting both the server and client machines doesn't solve the problem. 
Why does this happen? How to fix it?

Note: Ubuntu server 14.04 on both client and server